# Creating SVG through the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, svg, xhtml

### The project:

I'm currently undertaking a task of dynamically creating SVG elements through JS + jQuery. It's all going well, and I'm able to draw all the basic shapes onto the screen.

### The problem:

When I try and declare the shapes in a `<DEFS>` block, and draw with `<USE>`, nothing is drawn onto the screen.

### The confusion:

Although nothing is drawn onto the screen, if I inspect the dynamic DOM through Firebug or Chrome's Dev tools, the syntax is fine; I can even copy out the syntax, place in a `.SVG` file and it will work fine.

### Additional information:

- I'm using inline SVG
- Using xhtml as opposed to html
- Mainly using the jQuery framework
- Anything outside `USE` and `DEFS` work fine.

### My jQuery code:

```
var $root = $('#svgRoot');

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        init($root);

        var $defBlock = $(def(null, {}));
        $(ellipse('petal', {cx: '50%', cy: '50%', rx: '75', ry: '15'}, $defBlock));
        $(use(null, { x: '10%', y: '10%',   fill:'purple' , 'xlink:href':'#petal'}));

    });
```

These are all custom functions, 1st paramaters are the element IDs, everything else are attributes. The third parameter is optional. It specifies the parent to append to. If null, it appends to the root SVG node. If specified, it attatches to that parent.

### The output when inspecting with Chrome:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgRoot" version="1.1">
    <svg:defs xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <svg:ellipse id="petal" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="75" ry="15" />
    </svg:defs>
    <svg:use xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="10%" y="10%" fill="purple" xlink:href="#petal" />
</svg>
```

### Help!

Does anyone have any experience with code not being rendered, even though the underlying DOM is correct, and works when placed in an independent `.SVG` file?

### Edit: Under the bonnet

```
function createBasicNode(parent ,shape, id, attributes){
    var $tag = $(createSVG(shape));

    if(id != null){
        $tag.attr('id', id);
    }

    applyAttributes($tag, attributes);
    $tag.appendTo(parent);
    return $tag;
}

function def(id, attributes, parent){
    parent = (parent === undefined) ? $parent : parent;
    return $(createBasicNode(parent,'defs', id, attributes));
}

function use(id, attributes, parent){
    parent = (parent === undefined) ? $parent : parent;
    return $(createBasicNode(parent,'use', id, attributes));
}
```

Comment: The problem probably lies in the implementation of those custom functions. Can we see the implementation of at least one of them please?

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated the original to match your request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using [`createElementNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElementNS)?

You can't create namespaced elements with the regular `createElement()`. If you use prefixed name like in `createElement("svg:defs")` it'll end up being part of the tag name (there's no syntax for it, but imagine something like `<null:svg\:defs>`).

In browsers with HTML5 parser you can use `el.innerHTML = "<svg>…</svg>"` to create SVG-namespaced elements since `<svg>` is special-cased by the parser.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm using, with 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' as the first parameter.

Comment: However, would it make a difference that I'm creating a node with `document.createElementNS` and appending it to nested nodes?

Comment: As `USE` is using xlink, would it be required to use `setAttributeNS('xlink....', 'href)` instead of `.attr()` from jQuery?

Comment: @BlackBox yes, you'll need `setAttributeNS('http://',…)` too. I presume you also mean `<use>` rather than `<USE>` as XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: Great! Using `setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", REFERENCE_HERE );` for the `<use>` tag means it is now rendered onto the screen. Thanks for the guidance porneL.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you don't use the `svg` prefix on the tags. e.g.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svgRoot" version="1.1">
    <defs xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <ellipse id="petal" cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="75" ry="15" />
    </defs>
    <use xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="10%" y="10%" fill="purple" xlink:href="#petal" />
</svg>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. I added the namespaces on after it wasn't working in the first place. The actual SVG code works, you're right, but the issue was nothing displaying when the webpage loads, but does when I strip the code and place it in an SVG file.

Comment: Please read what I've been saying. The generated SVG works when I strip it from the Chrome inspector, but it doesn't draw to screen through the application.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome without placing it in an external svg file. That's what you want, right?

Comment: The jQuery snippet I posted generates SVG, the html page I have displays the generated SVG. Basic shapes are shown, but when I use DEFS and USE, it doesnt show the shapes. What the chrome inspector shows however, is that the syntax generated is correct. My issue is finding out why the syntax is correct but the results not showing at the same time.